# Loading resources while using ASP.NET Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, relative-path

This problem is driving me crazy...
I'm using ASP.Net's Forms Authentication. As you may know, forms authentication adds a query string to the url stating what page to return to after authenticating. This parameter is called ReturnURL.

My problem is, I can't seem to be able to load .js and .css files. I have to use a relative path.
This is how i'm finding the path to my resource files:

```
 <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>'></script>
```

This seems to be resolving the urls as it should. What i get in the page source, under the src atrribute are the actual correct paths to the files.

the thing is, i'm getting errors in the console saying:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <         Login.aspxReturnUrl=%2fClickCloudWeb%2fScripts%2fjquery1.4.1.js:3
```

it seams like he's adding the resource files path as the ReturnURL in the query string and isn't actually loading it.

Doe's anyone have an idea how to overcome this issue?
Thanks,
Uri

Answer (score 1):

Try with `<%=` instead of `<%#`. The latest is used for data bind contexts.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js")%>'>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I'm still getting this:
Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fClickCloudWeb%2fScripts%2fjquery-1.4.1.js
Also, i hav to use the <%# format with the data binding because of a different error i get when using <%=